# Having problems fully understanding GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going over some practise questions for an exam that I have coming up and I'm having a problem fully understanding group by. I see **GROUP BY** as the following: group the result set by one or more columns.

**I have the following database schema**

[image]

[image]

**My query**

```
SELECT orders.customer_numb, sum(order_lines.cost_line), customers.customer_first_name, customers.customer_last_name
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_numb = orders.customer_numb
INNER JOIN order_lines ON order_lines.order_numb = orders.order_numb
GROUP BY orders.customer_numb, order_lines.cost_line, customers.customer_first_name,     customers.customer_last_name
ORDER BY order_lines.cost_line DESC
```

**What I'm struggling to understand** 
Why can't I simply use just `GROUP BY orders.cost_line` and group the data by cost_line?

**What I'm trying to achieve** 
I'd like to achieve the name of the customer who has spent the most money. I just don't fully understand how to achieve this. I understand how joins work, I just can't seem to get my head around why I can't simply GROUP BY customer_numb and cost_line (with sum() used to calculate the amount spent). I seem to always get "not a GROUP BY expression", if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong (not just give me the answer), that would be great - I'd really appreciate that, and of course any resources that you have for using GROUP by properly.

Sorry for the long essay and If I've missed anything I apologise. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just can't seem to get my head around why I can't simply GROUP BY
>   customer_numb and cost_line (with sum() used to calculate the amount
>   spent).

When you say `group by customer_numb` you know that customer_numb uniquely identifies a row in the customer table (assuming customer_numb is either a primary or alternate key), so that any given `customers.customer_numb` will have one and only one value for `customers.customer_first_name` and `customers.customer_last_name`. But at parse time Oracle does not know, or at least acts like it does not know that. And it says, in a bit of panic, "What do I do if a single `customer_numb` has more than one value for `customer_first_name`?"

Roughly the rule is, expressions in the `select` clause can use expressions in the `group by` clause and/or use aggregate functions. (As well as constants and system variables that don't depend on the base tables, etc.) And by "use" I mean be the expression or part of the expression. So once you group on first name and last name, `customer_first_name || customer_last_name` would be a valid expression also.

When you have a table, like `customers` and are grouping by a primary key, or a column with a unique key and not null constraint, you can safely include them in `group by` clause. In this particular instance, `group by customer.customer_numb, customer.customer_first_name, customer.customer_last_name.`

Also note, that the `order by` in the first query will fail, since `order_lines.cost_line` doesn't have a single value for the group. You can order on `sum(order_lines.cost_line)` or use an column alias in the `select` clause and order on that `alias`

```
SELECT orders.customer_numb, 
    sum(order_lines.cost_line), 
    customers.customer_first_name, 
    customers.customer_last_name
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_numb = orders.customer_numb
INNER JOIN order_lines ON order_lines.order_numb = orders.order_numb
GROUP BY orders.customer_numb, 
    customers.customer_first_name, 
    customers.customer_last_name
ORDER BY sum(order_lines.cost_line)
```

or

```
SELECT orders.customer_numb, 
    sum(order_lines.cost_line) as sum_cost_line, 
. . .
ORDER BY sum_cost_line
```

Note: I've heard that some RDBMSes will imply additional expressions for the grouping without them being explicitly stated. Oracle is not one of those RDBMSes.

As for grouping by both `customer_numb` and `cost_line` Consider a DB with two customers, 1 and 2 with two orders of one line each:

```
Customer Number | Cost Line
              1 |     20.00
              1 |     20.00
              2 |     35.00
              2 |     30.00

 select customer_number, cost_line, sum(cost_line)
 FROM ...
 group by customer_number, cost_line
 order by sum(cost_line) desc

Customer Number | Cost Line | sum(cost_line)
              1 |     20.00 |          40.00
              2 |     35.00 |          35.00
              2 |     30.00 |          30.00
```

The first row with highest `sum(cost_line)` is not the customer who spent the most.

Comment: Very descriptive answer. I appreciate all the time put into this, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand how joins work, I just can't seem to get my head around
>   why I can't simply GROUP BY customer_numb and cost_line (with sum()
>   used to calculate the amount spent).

This should give you the sum for every customer.

```
SELECT orders.customer_numb, sum(order_lines.cost_line)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN order_lines ON order_lines.order_numb = orders.order_numb
GROUP BY orders.customer_numb
```

Note that every column in the SELECT clause that's *not* an argument to an aggregate function is also a column in the GROUP BY clause.

Now you can join that with other tables to get more detail. Here's one way using a common table expression. (There are other ways to express what you want.)

```
with customer_sums as (
    -- We give the columns useful aliases here.
    SELECT orders.customer_numb as customer_numb, 
           sum(order_lines.cost_line) as total_orders
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN order_lines ON order_lines.order_numb = orders.order_numb
    GROUP BY orders.customer_numb
)
select c.customer_numb, c.customer_first_name, c.customer_last_name, cs.total_orders
from customers c
inner join customer_sums cs
on cs.customer_numb = c.customer_numb
order by cs.total_orders desc
```

> Why can't I simply use just GROUP BY orders.cost_line and group the
>   data by cost_line?

Applying GROUP BY to order_lines.cost_line will give you one row for each distinct value in order_lines.cost_line.  (The column orders.cost_line doesn't exist.)  Here's what that data might look like.

```
OL.ORDER_NUMB OL.COST_LINE O.CUSTOMER_NUMB C.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME C.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME
--
1             1.45         2014            Julio                 Savell
1             2.33         2014            Julio                 Savell
1             1.45         2014            Julio                 Savell
2             1.45         2014            Julio                 Savell
2             1.45         2014            Julio                 Savell
3             13.00        2014            Julio                 Savell
```

You *can* group by order_lines.cost_line, but it won't give you any useful information.  This query

```
select order_lines.cost_line, orders.customer_numb
from order_lines
inner join orders on orders.customer_numb = order_lines.customer_numb
group by order_lines.cost_line;
```

should return something like this.

```
OL.COST_LINE O.CUSTOMER_NUMB 
--
1.45         2014
2.33         2014
13.00        2014
```

Not terribly useful.

If you're interested in the sum of the order line items, you need to decide what column or columns to group (summarize) by.  If you group (summarize) by order number, you'll get three rows. If you group (summarize) by customer number, you'll get one row.